# Bootstrap scrollable column with 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 columns using bootstrap, I am trying to have the right column to have `overflow-y: scroll` while hiding the scrollbar on `html, body`

The problem is, the scroll bar appears but it is disabled and unscrollable.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 text-center" id="left">
    <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="right">
        <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}
#left {
    background-color: #FC6E51;
}

#right {
    background-color: #4FC1E9;
}

#left, #right{
  text-align: center;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/ensc5uy1/9/

**EDIT** what @Chris and @Ben provided works inside JSFiddle but when I apply it in my application it doesn't work. I've created a new JSFiddle with my entire CSS and it works in there but no inside my app. I don't know what's going on

https://jsfiddle.net/5td0acad/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are not setting height to the parent containers of `#left` and `#right` divs.

You have to specify `height: 100%` to parent containers, i.e. `.container-fluid` and `.row`. However, I added additional class `.parent` to the `.row` container, because adding `height: 100%` to the `.row` class may affect the rest of the application layout. You may choose a better suiting name for your application.

You also have to set `overflow: auto`, in order the scrolbars to show only when there is overflow.

You can see it in action below:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
    background-color: #FC6E51;
}

.container-fluid, .parent{
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
    background-color: #4FC1E9;
}

#left, #right{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row parent">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 text-center" id="left">
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p>
      <p>Left contents END</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="right">
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p>
      <p>Right contents END</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working on JSFiddle but not in my application so I'm guessing I have a conflict in my CSS somewhere.

Comment: I put `.parent` class to the row, you may have add that class to you app  because addiing `height:100%` to your `.row` may affect the rest of the application

Comment: Yes, thank you. I understood that and I modified it accordingly. The weird thing is, I created a new JSFiddle with my entire CSS, it works there but not inside my application. https://jsfiddle.net/5td0acad/

Comment: I'm still having the same problem, the scroll bar appears but it is disabled and I cannot scroll through. I am trying to see what's causing this, the only this I found out is that WordPress is loading `bootstrap.css` instead of `bootstrap.min.css` but I'm not sure this would cause such a problem.

Comment: This - currently accepted answer - is not a good idea. This will - completely - destroy the responsiveness of your bootstrap layout.  As soon as the page is viewed at a width that will cause the columns to responsively shift - the shifting columns will become hidden under the remaining columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your CSS

```
.container-fluid, .row{
  height:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4Lcy1bn/)

You are using 100% height for both columns whilst they take up the entire width so only the left will show as it is taking up 100% of the page height. I'm assuming you are going to display them side by side otherwise you will only see one of the columns.

Comment: This is working on JSFiddle but not in my application so I'm guessing I have a conflict in my CSS somewhere.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your full CSS

Comment: This is JSFiddle with my entire CSS, weird thing is, it works there but not within my application. https://jsfiddle.net/5td0acad/

Comment: @Halnex That JSFiddle doesn't work. You've forgot to give ID's to the divs. You need to add the left and right IDs. Check this in your local code and see if you have missed them there.

Comment: I made sure, they are added locally and still scrollbar is disabled.

Comment: Are you able to put your entire code into a pastebin

Comment: I figured it out, I had an extra parent div with the id of `wrapper` that wasn't doing anything really. I removed it and boom it worked. I'm such a tool. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Alter CSS like this:

Height in `vh` instead of `%`

```
#left, #right{
 text-align: center;
 height:100vh;
 overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

Comment: `vh` are not compatible in older browser versions and explorer. He is correctly using the percentages as a unit. Something else is the problem

Comment: This displays the scrollbar correctly and I am able to scroll but it doesn't show the entire content in the column. It cuts off a little at the end. http://i.imgur.com/SBUiJL8.jpg

Comment: add some padding at bottom of `#left,#right`, Should work

Comment: @JonesJoseph Ok that works, thanks. But is this is the conventional way of doing things? I am not so sure about using `vh` instead of `%`

Comment: @Chris [See this Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) , Arent those more than enough?

Comment: @JonesJoseph I don't know what is enough, cause I did not ask the question. I agree it has good coverage, but in my application I would rather implement it with the good old percentages.